# Jquery add content text of an li element to a class

Tags: jquery

How can i get the content text of an element in order to use as class.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/somaberlin/H9RDv/)

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">blue</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">red</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">orange</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">green</a></li>
</ul>
```

after:

```
<ul>
   <li class="blue"><a href="#">blue</a></li>
   <li class="red"><a href="#">red</a></li>
   <li class="orange"><a href="#">orange</a></li>
   <li class="green"><a href="#">green</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use the `.addClass()` callback function and `.text()` method:

```
$('ul li').addClass(function() {
   return $(this).text();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3hV28/

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. You basically set the `class` attribute to the `text` value.

http://jsfiddle.net/H9RDv/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "li" ).each(function() {
    var text = $(this).find('a').text();
    $( this ).addClass(text);
});
```

Like so

Answer (score 1):

Try this :
Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/H9RDv/13/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "li" ).each(function() {
    cl = $(this).text();
    $( this ).addClass(cl);
});
});
```

Output:

```
<ul>
    <li class="item1"><a href="#">item1</a></li>
    <li class="item2"><a href="#">item2</a></li>
    <li class="item3"><a href="#">item3</a></li>
    <li class="item4"><a href="#">item4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Obeck : did you try this?